# Softcoding vs Hardcoding default value

Tags: java, design-patterns, coding-style

I am writing a wrapper for one api. Let's call it as "Foo".

Foo request takes a batch on 20 object in single api response. So My api wrapper takes two object for each request:

1. Request Object
2. Object of request configuration

Where Request Configuration contains following value.

```
final int maxBatchSize = 20;
volatile int sleepBetweenTwoBatches = 0;
```

Now it process given object, in multiple batches.

Do I need to move following to config?

1. `maxBatchSize`. As it never suppose to change. Putting it is config will have a risk a app modifying the value and seeing invalid input response from server.
2. Default value of `sleepBetweenTwoBatches`. Is it not already a configuration as you are specifying for each request?

Comment: Is anyone ever going to want/need to change these parameters?

Comment: @oliver-charlesworth
1) maxBatchSize : Only if server changes it's implementation.  Starts taking more than 20 element in each batch. 
2) sleepBetweenTwoBatches: Yes it can be application specific. But my point it they may need to write a factory method for each app. So this can be done there.

Answer (score 0):

*Do I need to move following to config?*

Of course not. If you're familiar with Thoughtworks' Technology Radar, they've been warning against the dangers of over-configuration for years.

http://www.thoughtworks.com/radar/tools/code-in-configuration
http://www.thoughtworks.com/radar/techniques/minimizing-application-configuration

> We are a big fan of minimizing application configuration, trying to
>   ensure that applications work sensibly out of the box with the bare
>   minimum of Configuration.

Hear, hear!